# ¿Cómo haces scrapping de una página mediante rvest?

Tags: r, rvest

Me pregunto si es posible hacer un scraping de esta web:

https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/

Lo que me gustaría es que cogiera a cada jugador (ya sea desde la pestaña del equipo o desde aquí: https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugadores/?pagina=1), que entrase en su perfil y fuese almacenando el Valor de mercado en un dataframe junto a su nombre. No sé si es posible, ya que de momento solo tengo familiaridad con el paquete rvest para sacar datos de una tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En teoría podrías, no hay ningún javascript en el medio. La única limitante, es que previamente deberías saber y establecer la cantidad de páginas a recuperar, o en su defecto, ir probando por distintos números de página hasta que tengas un error, por ejemplo

```
https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugadores/?pagina=1
https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugadores/?pagina=2
..
https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugadores/?pagina=n
```

Con cada `url` podrías en primer lugar obtener la lista de jugadores y construir dinámicamente la `url` para cada uno de ellos:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)

# Probamos con la primer página del listado
url <- "https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugadores/?pagina=1"
url %>%
    # leemos el HTML
    read_html() %>%
    # Obtenemos el nodo correspondiente a la tabla
    # Hay que obtener el xpath inspeccionando el objeto html
    html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/table') %>%
    # Llenamos la tabla
    html_table(fill= TRUE) %>% 
    # Extraemos la 4ta columna (nombre)
    map(`[[`,4) %>% 
    # le damos nombre a la columna y lo convertimos en un data.frame
    setNames("nombre") %>% 
    data.frame() %>% 
    # armamos la url para cada jugador
    # quitamos acentos, reemplazamos espacios por - y agregamos el base path
    mutate(url = tolower(nombre)) %>% 
    map_at("url", stri_trans_general,"Latin-ASCII") %>% 
    map_at("url", str_replace, ' ', '-') %>% 
    map_at("url",~paste0("https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/", .x)) %>% 
    bind_rows() -> jugadores
```

El resultado sería un `data.frame` que simplemente deberías ir agregando a otro general donde terminarías teniendo todos los jugadores, algo como esto:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   nombre         url                                                   
   <fct>          <chr>                                                 
 1 Messi          https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/messi         
 2 Stuani         https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/stuani        
 3 Luis Suárez    https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/luis-suarez   
 4 Ben Yedder     https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/ben-yedder    
 5 Canales        https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/canales       
 6 Piqué          https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/pique         
 7 Jony Rodríguez https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/jony-rodriguez
 8 Jorge Molina   https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/jorge-molina  
 9 Morales        https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/morales       
10 Sarabia        https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/sarabia       
11 Jaime Mata     https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/jaime-mata    
12 Oyarzábal      https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/oyarzabal     
13 Rubén Peña     https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/ruben-pena    
14 Borja Iglesias https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/borja-iglesias
15 Laguardia      https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/laguardia     
16 Dembélé        https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/dembele       
17 Benzema        https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/benzema       
18 Jesús Navas    https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/jesus-navas   
19 Griezmann      https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/griezmann     
20 Cazorla        https://www.jornadaperfecta.com/jugador/cazorla
```

Finalmente con todas las `urls` podrías hacer consultas para cada página y procesar el html para encontrar el dato que estás buscando (no sé si el dato que use en esta prueba es el adecuado, pero imagino que se entiende la idea):

```
jugadores$url %>% 
    # leemos el HTML de cada url
    map(read_html) %>% 
    # obtenemos el objeto de valor de mercado
    map(html_nodes,xpath="/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[4]") %>%
    # Convertimos el dato a texto
    map_chr(html_text) %>% 
    # Separamos por el espaci y no quedamos con el 3 elemento
    # queremos solo los números
    str_split(" ") %>% 
    map_chr(`[[`, 3) %>% 
    # Borramos los puntos y convertimos los valores a números
    str_remove_all('\\.') %>% 
    as.numeric() -> jugadores$vm
```

Finalmente la salida sería algo así:

```
jugadores %>% 
    select(nombre, vm)

# A tibble: 20 x 2
   nombre               vm
   <fct>             <dbl>
 1 Messi          35160000
 2 Stuani         18790000
 3 Luis Suárez    24890000
 4 Ben Yedder     18200000
 5 Canales        14790000
 6 Piqué          12690000
 7 Jony Rodríguez 12980000
 8 Jorge Molina   10540000
 9 Morales        15480000
10 Sarabia        19360000
11 Jaime Mata      4260000
12 Oyarzábal      18180000
13 Rubén Peña      7500000
14 Borja Iglesias 16670000
15 Laguardia       6190000
16 Dembélé        18740000
17 Benzema        14500000
18 Jesús Navas    11710000
19 Griezmann      22560000
20 Cazorla         7160000
```

Por último, hacer esto lleva su tiempo, y además es posible que la página lo detecte como algún tipo de ataque (hasta ahora no me ha pasado), pero eventualmente podría bloquearte, por lo que deberás experimentar. **No está de mas decirte que el scraping, puede ser considerado por el titular del sitio, como un ataque o un acto delictivo, te recomiendo que contactes a los administradores, para consultar este tema en particular**, eventualmente tengan disponible alguna API que incluso haga más sencillo todo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Una duda respecto al código, que lo he visto en alguna ocasión y todavía no he encontrado nada que me lo resuelva, qué significa esto?  map_chr(`[[`, 3) Me refiero a la parte de [[ . Es que al usar el operador pipe con eso muestras que te refieres el archivo de antes?

Comment: Todas las funciones del tipo `map` "aplican" una determinada función a cada elemento de una lista, en el caso de `map_chr([[, 3) ` al venir de una lista de listas, aplica un subset de listas `[[]]` para quedarnos con el 3 elemento