# Error al descargar y descomprimir unos archivos desde una dirección URL en mac en Rstudio

Tags: r, rutas, rstudio, zip, macos

Quiero descargar, descomprimir y unir datos desde una url
ftp://www.ine.es/temas/frontur/

Para los siguientes años y meses

`meses = 1:12`
`años = 16:18`

Para leer desde la pagina web hice lo siguiente :

```
for (i in meses) 
  for (j in años) {
    fichero <- paste("datos_",i,"_",j,".zip",sep="")
    miurl <- paste("ftp://www.ine.es/temas/frontur/",fichero, sep="")
    download.file(miurl, destfile = paste(".\\zips\\",fichero, sep=""))
  }
```

Me aparece que se descargan todos los archivos, sin embargo, no en la carpeta zips que cree en el directorio de trabajo (y no se donde lo hace) como se espera

```
==================================================
trying URL 'ftp://www.ine.es/temas/frontur/datos_12_16.zip'
Content type 'unknown' length 296434 bytes (289 KB)
==================================================
```

Para desempaquetar los zip

```
zips <- dir(".\\zips",pattern = "zip")
for(i in zips) {
  unzip(paste(".\\zips\\",i, sep=""), exdir = ".\\zips")
}
```

Cuando corro esta segunda parte me aparece: `character(0)`

Para unir los ficheros de texto

```
ftex <- dir(".\\zips",pattern = "txt")
n1 <- paste(".\\zips\\", ftex[1], sep="")
```

Pues como no descarga, no sé si los script de descomprimir y unir funcionan.

Comment: Bienvenido @JavierDeLaHoz a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente cuando se trabaja con varios directorios y archivos, se hace necesario gestionar de alguna manera lo anterior.

Cuando se está en **macOS** lo más probable es tener un directorio `"default"`dónde habitualmente se trabaja en **RStudio**.

```
/Users/elNombreDeLaMac/Desktop/directorio(s)
```

Voy a trabajar este ejemplo en el directorio

```
 /Users/elNombreDeLaMac/Desktop/downZip
```

Siendo el nombre del script `downloadZip.R`. Asimismo voy a guardar en dicho script el actual directorio de trabajo `/Users/elNombreDeLaMac/Desktop/directorio(s)`:

```
defaultDir<-getwd()
```

Como flujo de trabajo recomiendo construir una función de ayuda que administre los directorios de descarga y posible archivos de aquellos gráficos que se necesiten guardar.

```
#----------------------------------------
# FUNCION DE AYUDA
# gestor y creador de subdirectorios
# dentro del script downloadZip.R
#----------------------------------------
manageDir <- function(mainDir, subDir){
    dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir), showWarnings = FALSE)
    setwd(paste0(mainDir,"/",subDir))
}
```

Para este caso concreto se trabaja en la siguiente ruta

```
# se trabaja en esta ruta
setwd("/Users/elNombreDeLaMac/Desktop/downZip")
```

Luego hay que definir el directorio dónde estará el script `downloadZip.R` y en qué carpeta se va ha guardar y descomprimir los **archivos zip**.

```
# se define el subdirectorio donde se guardan los zip
# en relacion al directorio principal (actual)
mainDir<-getwd()
subDir<-"Archivos Zip"
```

Después se emplea la función de ayuda para crear la carpeta: **"Archivos Zip"** y dejarla por un momento como directorio **default**

```
# se crea el subdiretorio "Archivos Zip"
# y se le elige momentaneamente
# como zona de trabajo
manageDir(mainDir, subDir)
```

Una vez hecho los pasos anteriores, *-que son sólo una recomendación-* se procede a descargar y descomprimir los archivos respectivos.

```
meses<-1:12; anios<-16:18
for (i in meses) 
    for (j in anios) {

        # se crea cada url de acuerdo al nombre del fichero
        fichero <- paste0("datos_",i,"_",j,".zip")
        miurl <- paste0("ftp://www.ine.es/temas/frontur/",fichero)

        # se verifica descarga del archivo
        if(!file.exists(fichero)){download.file(miurl,fichero, mode="wb")}

        # se verifica si está descomprimido en el subdirectorio
        if(!file.exists(subDir)){unzip(fichero)}
    }
```

Después se tiene que volver a la carpeta donde está el script y verificar los archivos descargados, y aquí siento decir que no tienen el mismo nombre que el `zip` y son del tipo `txt`, pero esto es sencillo de arreglar con la función `list.files` de **R**

```
# se vuelve a la carpeta
# donde se encuentra el script
setwd(mainDir)

# se verifica que este la información 
# en la carpeta "Archivos Zip"
# esto puede ser almacenado en un vector para su posterior
# lectura
list.files(path = subDir, pattern = "\\.txt$")

 [1] "datos_frontur0116.txt"    "datos_frontur0117def.txt" "datos_frontur0118def.txt"
 [4] "datos_frontur0216.txt"    "datos_frontur0217def.txt" "datos_frontur0218.txt"   
 [7] "datos_frontur0316.txt"    "datos_frontur0317def.txt" "datos_frontur0318.txt"   
[10] "datos_frontur0416.txt"    "datos_frontur0417def.txt" "datos_frontur0418.txt"   
[13] "datos_frontur0516.txt"    "datos_frontur0517def.txt" "datos_frontur0518.txt"   
[16] "datos_frontur0616.txt"    "datos_frontur0617def.txt" "datos_frontur0618.txt"   
[19] "datos_frontur0716.txt"    "datos_frontur0717def.txt" "datos_frontur0718.txt"   
[22] "datos_frontur0816.txt"    "datos_frontur0817def.txt" "datos_frontur0818.txt"   
[25] "datos_frontur0916.txt"    "datos_frontur0917def.txt" "datos_frontur0918.txt"   
[28] "datos_frontur1016.txt"    "datos_frontur1017def.txt" "datos_frontur1018.txt"   
[31] "datos_frontur1116.txt"    "datos_frontur1117def.txt" "datos_frontur1118.txt"   
[34] "datos_frontur1216.txt"    "datos_frontur1217def.txt" "datos_frontur1218.txt"
```

Si ya no es necesario usar este script y antes de cerrarlo se quiere volver al directorio habitual de trabajo

```
# terminado todo antes de salir de RStudio
# o empezar a trabajar con otro script
# en otro directorio
setwd(defaultDir)
getwd()
# /Users/elNombreDeLaMac/Desktop/directorio(s)
```

Finalmente siguiendo los pasos anteriores se debería poder visualizar lo siguiente en el **Finder** de la **mac**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota:** he visto que algunos archivos no han sido descargados

```
ftp://www.ine.es/temas/frontur/disreg_frontur1215.zip
ftp://www.ine.es/temas/frontur/disreg_frontur15.zip
ftp://www.ine.es/temas/frontur/disreg_frontur16.zip
```

> Esto se debe a que no coinciden con los patrones generados a partir de los bucles `for` anidados , si se desea bajar la lista completa de la página web (un método generalizado), sugiero se revise este enlace: [¿Cómo haces scrapping de una página mediante rvest?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245410/c%C3%B3mo-haces-scrapping-de-una-p%C3%A1gina-mediante-rvest)